# JavaScript password generator creating strange character

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created a simple password generator using javascript.

When you click the button on the page, it creates you a password and displays it below.
This password generator creates a string containing the following:

8 random letters from a-z.

2 random numbers from 0-9.

1 random special character from an array of strings. (see array 'chars').

However, after you click the button a few times, eventually, a password will be generated with 2 special characters, with a 'Â' in it. I'm confused because this character isnt in the chars array.

Why is this, and is there anyway to tell the JS to not include that character in particular?

```js
function myFunction() {
  // create initial arrays.
  a = [];
  var chars = ['#', '%', '£', '!', '?', '&'];
  for (var i = 97; i <= 122; i++) {
    a[a.length] = String.fromCharCode(i).toUpperCase();

    // create random letters.
    var one = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)];
    var two = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)];
    var three = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)];
    var four = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)];
    var five = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)];
    var six = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)];
    var seven = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)];
    var eight = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)];

    // create random numbers.
    var int1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    var int2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    var ints = int1.toFixed(0) + int2.toFixed(0);
    var intsDecimal = int1.toFixed(0) + "." + int2.toFixed(0);

    // create random characters, based on array (chars).
    var randChar = chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length).toFixed(0)];

    // create variable moving all letters, numbers and characters together.
    var c = one + two + three + four + five + six + seven + eight + ints + randChar;
  }
  // display variable c.
  document.getElementById('userPass').innerHTML = c;
}
```

```html
<p>Using simple JS to create a random password.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">CLICK</button>

<h4>Your password is:</h4>
<h3 id="userPass"></h3>
```

Comment: FYI: Math.random() is not a secure way to generate passwords.

Comment: I have seen nothing, it's not dirt on your screen, is it?

Comment: @John I can select the character with my cursor, so unfortunately not.

Comment: When you build randChar, try setting its inputs and outputting them as well.  I've clicked this several too many times and haven't seen any odd characters.  What are the input vars when you get Â?

Comment: FYI, you're doing all your logic for each iteration of the `for` loop but you're only using the last result. Shouldn't the `for` loop be solely to populate the `a` array? Also, use `var` when declaring `a` otherwise it won't be scoped.

Comment: What character encoding are you actually saving the file in and does it match the encoding declared in the document / meta...

Comment: @Emissary I just added <meta charset="UTF-8"> to the markup and it does appear that the character is no longer appearing! Thank you :)

Comment: @MikaelLennholm You're right, changes have been made. thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Generate a password using a specific pattern like 3 UpperCase, 3 lowercase, special char, and digit all lengths as you like.

```
const generatePassword = (str, limit) =>{
    let password = "";
        for (let i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
               let char = Math.floor(Math.random()
                           * str.length);
               password += str.charAt(char)
           }
      return password;
}

let password = () => {
           let ucstr = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            let lcstr = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
            let digitstr = '0123456789';
            let spstr = '@#$';
            
           const password = generatePassword(ucstr, 5) + generatePassword(lcstr, 3)  + generatePassword(digitstr, 2)  + generatePassword(spstr, 2);
           return password;
       }
console.log("Your Password us ===> ", password());
```

Sample Output is **AXTSFadsf34#@**